# How to use timer in escrow

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereum-classic

I have an **escrow contract** where party *A* is sending some token to party *B* and right now held in escrow. I want to use the **timer function** in smart contract so that the token will be held for a certain period of time. After that time, the token will be reverted back to ***originator account***, that is party *A*.

I am **adding the escrow in an ERC20 smart contract so I can call it inside the smart contract**.

How can I create a holding frame of 30 days in smart contract and after 30 days the token will be reverted back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, for instance, have the function that creates the escrow to save the date of expiration

```
function createEscrow(...){
    expirationDate = now + 30 days;
    // more code for your escrow
}
```

The to finalize the escrow you add in your function

```
function endEscrow(...){
    require(expirationDate < now);
    // more code for your escrow finalization
}
```

If you want this to be executed automatically you can use services like [ETH-Tempus](https://github.com/jfdelgad/ETH-Tempus), that schedule execution of contracts and is available on Rinkeby for free.

Disclaimer: I wrote the code for ETH-Tempus